# Wordpress not showing posts (Griddist theme)

Tags: wordpress

I just recently updated my version of wordpress to 5.6.1. Website is [www.americano.site](http://www.americano.site)

I used to have a set of posts display under "miscelanea/projects" (this is the category name). Now when I access this from the side menu, it doesn't show anything. It seems to connect to the right content, as when you hover the mouse around it shows the posts it is supposed to show, but it is a blank page.

I have very limited knowledge of code but reading through other posts it seems the problem has to do with javascript (main.js file missing). If so, can anybody tell me how to download and upload this to fix this error?

I'm using the Griddist theme by Superb (but problem persists in other themes too)

Comment: Please update theme as well if you are using WP default theme or child theme.

Comment: I just did by downloading the theme anew and uploading it to wordpress. I replaced the old version and now it's working fine! Thank you so much for the suggestion :)